# Проблема с обновлением кода в Google Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Доброго вечера народ! У меня такая проблемка, почему если например сделать Навигацию шириной в 400px и открыть его в гугл хроме в первый раз то он все показывает корректно, но если изменить ширину навигации с 400 на 700pх и снова открыть в браузере, то Хром все-равно показывает навигацию шириной в 400px, а если я удаляю историю захода сайта и снова захожу как-будто в первый раз, тогда навигация становиться в 700рх. Вообщем любые изменения в коде обновляются в Хроме только если каждый раз чистить историю. Почему так???

P.S.В Mozilla и др. все работает отлично и не надо чистить историю после каждого изменения кода.

Comment: жми комбинацию Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 1):

Проблема появилась в [версии 56](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/12/chrome-56-beta-not-secure-warning-web.html). Теперь браузер полноценнее использует локальный кэш. Из-за того, что количество проверочных запросов к серверу уменьшилось на 60%, скорость перезагрузки страниц увеличилась до 28%. Однако из-за этого браузер не может теперь корректно определить, что CSS обновился.

Для того, чтобы загружать каждый новый CSS, можно использовать такую комбинацию:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css?<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

PHP-вставка подставляет текущее время и получается следующий код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css?1401823964">
```

Правда, данный вариант нe совсем правильный и стоит писать более продвинутое создание версионности CSS.